# issues related to implementation of Visitor Design Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

Based on my current requirement, I have implemented the Visitor pattern and we have some different aspects as follows:

1>Different from the classic example illustrated in the GoF book, subclasses of Equipment are not flatted. In other words, subclasses are all in the hierarchy.

For example:
    //Flat 
    EquipmentA : public Equipment {}
    EquipmentB : public Equipment {}
    EquipmentC : public Equipment {}

```
//hierarchy
EquipmentA : public Equipment {}
EquipmentB : public EquipmentA {}
EquipmentC : public EquipmentB {}
```

2> Subclass has some specialized functions that are not virtual functions defined in the base.
For example:

```
`EquipmentA` may define a function called `GetFactorRate`
`EquipmentB` may define a function called `GetAmplifyRate`
```

Keep all these in mind, here is my code.

**Question 1**> Does the code have any problems?

**Question 2**> Should I concern the block I marked as "Note"
i.e. what if `SpecialFloppyDisk` calls `VisitFloppyDisk` instead of `SpecialVisitFloppyDisk`.
I believe good code is designed in a way that enable it difficult to make mistakes. But I am not sure whether this case applies here.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class FloppyDisk;
class SpecialFloppyDisk;
class EquipmentVisitor
{
public:
    virtual ~EquipmentVisitor() {}    
    // modify Equipment based on different subclass of Equipment
    virtual void VisitFloppyDisk(FloppyDisk&) = 0;
    virtual void VisitSpecialFloppyDisk(SpecialFloppyDisk&) = 0;

    int GetTotalPrice() const { return m_iTotalPrice; }
protected:
    int m_iTotalPrice;    
protected:
    EquipmentVisitor() {}
};    
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Equipment {
public:
    virtual ~Equipment() {}    
    // return the price of the Equipment
    virtual int GetPrice() const = 0;

    virtual void Accept(EquipmentVisitor&) = 0;
protected:
    Equipment() {}
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class FloppyDisk : public Equipment
{
public:
    // return the price of the Equipment
    virtual int GetPrice() const {return 100;}
    int GetFactorRate() const {return 2; } // x 2

    virtual void Accept(EquipmentVisitor& e){e.VisitFloppyDisk(*this);}
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class SpecialFloppyDisk : public FloppyDisk
{
public:
    virtual std::string GetName() const {return std::string("Bus");}            
    // return the price of the Equipment
    virtual int GetPrice() const {return 20000;}

    int GetAmplifyRate() const {return 11; }// x 11
    virtual void Accept(EquipmentVisitor& e)
    {
        e.VisitSpecialFloppyDisk(*this);
        // Note: if called the following function by accident, then it introduces
        // hidden bugs!!!!
        // e.VisitFloppyDisk(*this);
    }
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class PricingVisitor : public EquipmentVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void VisitFloppyDisk(FloppyDisk& e)
    {m_iTotalPrice = e.GetPrice() * e.GetFactorRate();}
    virtual void VisitSpecialFloppyDisk(SpecialFloppyDisk& e)
    {   m_iTotalPrice = e.GetPrice() * e.GetAmplifyRate(); }
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PricingVisitor pricingVisitor;
    SpecialFloppyDisk specialFloppyDisk;
    FloppyDisk floppyDisk;

    floppyDisk.Accept(pricingVisitor);
    // output: pricingVisitor.GetTotalPrice(): 200
    // i.e. 100 x 2
    std::cout << "pricingVisitor.GetTotalPrice(): " << pricingVisitor.GetTotalPrice() << std::endl;

    // output: pricingVisitor.GetTotalPrice(): 220000
    // i.e. 20000 x 11
    specialFloppyDisk.Accept(pricingVisitor);
    std::cout << "pricingVisitor.GetTotalPrice(): " << pricingVisitor.GetTotalPrice() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should probably be on code reviews, that's a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1: Any problems? Yes, they are. Design problems:**

1. `EquipmentVisitor` shall not have  `GetTotalPrice()/m_iTotalPrice`. It should be pure class containing only Visit stuff. Visitor pattern is mainly for adding new functionality to classes family (in this case Equipment) without modifying these classes. If adding other Visitor - then it would be, most probably, not interested in equipment prices. If it will be interested in pricing - then it should derive from `PricingVisitor`.
2. Move price stuff to  PricingVisitor, This is the right place for it.
3. Do not make different names for different `Visit` methods. Compiler will selected the right method in `Accept` basing on `*this` type.

**Q2: what if SpecialFloppyDisk calls VisitFloppyDisk instead of SpecialVisitFloppyDisk:**

Already mentioned in Q1.3 - do not use different names - thus you avoid problems.

```
class EquipmentVisitor
{
public:
   virtual ~EquipmentVisitor() {}    
   virtual void Visit(FloppyDisk&) = 0;
   virtual void Visit(SpecialFloppyDisk&) = 0;
};
```